# Custom Font Mixed Content Error WordPress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

[image]I am using WordPress. I recently added SSL in my domain. However, fonts .ttf and .woff remains loads in HTTP not HTTPS. Please help me how to fix this? I am using Bimber Theme on my domain technocombo.com

Answer (score 1):

Find the links for the fonts in your theme's functions.php, header.php or other file(s) and do one of two things:

1) add an s to http, so the links are https

or

2), remove the http: to make the link protocol agnostic, i.e. `//technocombo.com/wp-content/themes/bimder/etc/path/to/font/font.wof`

Either way, that will solve the mixed content errors. Check with dev tools.

And, make a child theme of Bimber so you don't lose these changes when Bimber is updated. See [Child Themes | Theme Developer Handbook | WordPress Developer Resources](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/)